# Find whether an element contains in a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have,

```
<a id="a123"></a>
```

Now I need to check whether $("a") selector contains $("#a123") element.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [.attr('id')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Are you looking to see if the set returned by the selector has an element with that ID, or a child with that ID?  If the former, Mike is correct.  If the latter then Shankar is your man.  But I read your question the way Mike did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find whether `a` has this `a123` id then you can do it using `is` method which returns `true` if it matches the selector else returns false.

```
if($("a").is('#a123')){
     //It is #a123
}
```

If you want to find if `a` contains child with id `a123` then use `has` method which reduces the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element..

```
if($("a").has('#a123').length > 0){
     //It contains child with #a123
}
```

References:

- `is()` - http://api.jquery.com/is/
- `has()` - http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: Much more elegant than mine. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks, looks very fine for me.

Comment: is is working fine for me. I have a jquery object(say $obA = $("#a123")) and a jquery selector object $objB = $("a"). I need to check whther $objB contains the object $obA. Not sure what is best is or has.

Comment: @user960567 - Use `has()` method if you want to check any element contains some element within it.

Comment: But according to is documentation, "Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments."

Comment: That definition is for `is()` and not `has()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").filter("#a123").size() > 0
```

Comment: This is my solution too.  Filter is your friend and useful for lots of similar situations to this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use.attr("id") to pull back the value of the id.  Then you can use an **if** statement to check if the value is what you expected.